# collapse / aggregate multiple rows into single row with shared percentage based on same IDs

Tags: dplyr, aggregate, data-cleaning

I need some advice/hint on how to aggregate rows shared IDs to get percentage data.

I have the data frame formatted as:

```
id  county_1   country_2     country_3  .... country_x  sum_by_id
1    10              0           0               0       100
1    0               20          0               0       100
1    0               0          70               0       100
2    10              0           0              20        80
2    0               20          0               0        80       
2    0               10         20               0        80      
3   ...
3   ...

# noted sum_by_id is the sum from country_1 to country_x/ based on shared IDs.
```

What I hope to get is:

```
id  county_1   country_2     country_3   ... country_x
1    0.1          0.2           0.7            0
2    0.125        0.375         0.25           0.25         
3    ...
4    ...

# FYI. For project ID"2", 0.375 = (20+10)/80
```

I am stuck to find examples for this kind of aggregation. It would be greatly appreciated if someone can point me to right place to look at or offer some suggestions on this issue.

Thanks!

To reproduce the data,

```
# Required packages
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Data
df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
                  country_1 = c(10,0, 0, 10,0,0), 
                  country_2 = c(0,20, 0, 0, 20, 10),
                  country_3 = c(0,0, 70, 0, 0, 20),
                  country_x = c(0,0,0,20,0,0))

df1 <- df1 %>% mutate(sum_by_id = across(starts_with("country_"))%>%rowSums )
```

Comment: I believe this it not too difficult. Can you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example) so that we can actually use your data to get an answer? Particularly, use the `dput()` function to generate R code to recreate your data.

Comment: sure! I added it. I was wondering if aggregate(., ~id, data= df1, Fun= sum) helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the most elegant solution, but it works.

```
# Required packages
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Data
df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
                  country_1 = c(10,0, 0, 10,0,0), 
                  country_2 = c(0,20, 0, 0, 20, 10),
                  country_3 = c(0,0, 70, 0, 0, 20),
                  country_x = c(0,0,0,20,0,0))
```

Note: Skipping the step of creating your `sum_by_id`

```
df1 %>% 
        pivot_longer(-id, names_to = "country", values_to = "value") %>%
        summarise(value = sum(value), .by = c(id, country)) %>%
        mutate(
                value = value / sum(value),
                .by = id
        ) %>%
        pivot_wider(names_from = country, values_from = value)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 5
     id country_1 country_2 country_3 country_x
  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1     0.1       0.2        0.7       0   
2     2     0.125     0.375      0.25      0.25
```

#### EDIT:

It also works without pivoting wider/longer. It's a little bit confusing though.

```
df1 %>% 
        group_by(id) %>% 
        summarise(across(contains("country"), sum)) %>% 
        mutate(across(contains("country"), \(x) x / rowSums(select(., contains("country")))))

# A tibble: 2 × 5
     id country_1 country_2 country_3 country_x
  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1     0.1       0.2        0.7       0   
2     2     0.125     0.375      0.25      0.25
```

Comment: Hi Ludwig. Thank you!  My original dataset is actually a long dataframe which includes a country column called "country" and "amount". I made it wide to create multiple dummies from country_1 to country_x. I also create a series of numeric var by multiplying amount with each country dummy (amt_x_dummy). I wonder use your first method, I don't need to use pivot_longer command right since I already have the two long columns. My concern here is if using mutate to create a new var "mutate(share_value = amt/ total_amt, na.rm= TRUE), .by = c(id, country)),  id and country is not unique id.

Comment: I think that you don’t need the pivot longer then, yes. I would have to see the data, it’s not clear to me what you mean @Sam